# Input text value separated by commas

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I tried:

```
success: function (result) {
    for (var i = 0; i < result.d.length; i++) {
        var emls = new Array();
        emls = result.d[i].Emailid;
        alert(emls);
        $("#EmailCC").val(emls);                                                                                        
    }
}
```

In the alert, I am getting all the values of the result but text box shows only the last value of the result.

Comment: `$("#EmailCC").val(emls);` will replace value if you want all values then put it in an array first them put the array in the input

Comment: `$("#EmailCC").val(emls)` is the problem, it selects the element with id `EmailCC` and adds each value to it, so that's why it shows only the last id.

Answer (score 2):

`$("#EmailCC").val(emls);` will overwrite the previous value, hence you are only getting the last email id.

Create an array of email ids using [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) then use [`Array.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) to create a comma separate string

```
success: function (result) {
    var emails = result.d.map(x => x.Emailid);
    $("#EmailCC").val(emails.join(','));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are overwriting email value each time. try below code

```
success: function (result) {
    var emails = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < result.d.length; i++) {
        var emls = new Array();
        emls = result.d[i].Emailid;
        emails += emls + ",";
    }
    $("#EmailCC").val(emails);
```

Answer (score 0):

Little modification here.

```
success: function (result) {
    var emls = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < result.d.length; i++) {
        emls.push(result.d[i].Emailid);                                                                                     
    }
    $("#EmailCC").val(emls.join(", "));
}
```